# How to calculate portable power station draining with other loads?

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, battery-charging, load

I want to buy a portable power station, it's basically a battery, the battery capacity at 14.8V/15Ah is 222Wh, I want to know how many times it will long for some loads, such as a simple light , or how much it will last for my phone charger that has 44W fast charger with my phone battery capacity 4500 mAh, I don't know how to calculate all of this to buy the right portable power station for me

Comment: It will last 222Wh / 44W = 5 hours of phone charging.

Comment: I agree with @MichalPodmanický. In general, portable power stations will be rather disappointing given their cost. It's often quite surprising just how much power various devices use. For example, a AA battery provides about 10,000 Joules. That is enough energy to launch a 1 kg mass (about 2.2 lbs) to a height of 1 km (about 0.6 miles) of height! That's just *one* AA battery! Most people have very little idea about just how much energy they use, day to day. It's almost scary when you get a clue about it.

Comment: @jonk of course that would be in an ideal world with 100% efficiency and no air. Not likely to happen any time soon.

Comment: @jcaron I'm only pointing out the magnitude of the problem. The point remains, regardless.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický great, the battery data written are 14.8V/15Ah, how many times I could charge my phone battery which is 4200mAh, if we assume that the phone charger is 44w?